# Azure SDK C# Convert Page Blob to VHD?

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, vhd

I have copied two VHDs into blob storage as page blobs. Using the SDK API wrappers from C#, how can I let Azure know that one is an OS disk, and one is a data disk? I want to set this up so I can then use the regular v1 portal GUI to create a new VM using the disks I uploaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you don't have to do anything special. You can simply create disks out of these page blobs (as long as they are valid VHDs) and start using them.

[image]

[image]

Once you do this, you should be able to create VM using OS disk and attach data disks to it.

For more information on attaching a disk to VM, you may find this link useful: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-windows-attach-disk/.

Comment: I wanted to know how to do that using C# code, not using the GUI. But thanks.